# Print from Bison an XML file

Tags: xml, printing, bison

I'm a little bit confused about how to print from Bison. I have a project in which I have to take a file with text as an input and check if it is correct as XML. I have written the BNF in Bison and I'd like to print the text from the input file in the stdout  if it's correct. I know I can also print it from the flex but this isn't what we are asked to do in the project.This is a part of my bnf:

`WORKBOOK: WORKBOOK_START INWORKBOOK WORKBOOK_END  ;`

`INWORKBOOK: WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS | NUM_STYLES WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS
      ;`

`MORE_WORKSHEETS:  WORKSHEET MORE_WORKSHEETS | ;`

`NUM_STYLES: STYLES NUM_STYLES | ;`

`STYLES: STYLES_START  INSTYLES STYLES_END  ;`

`INSTYLES: STYLE INSTYLES | ;`

`STYLE: STYLE_START INSTYLE STYLE_END ;`

`INSTYLE: id CLOSE_TAG ;`

`id: ID EQUAL QUOTES STRING QUOTES ;`

WORKBOOK_START, WORKBOOK_END etc are terminal tokens which I want to print.
And here is a part of my flex code and how I print from flex.

```
"<ss:Workbook>"     {printf("%s",yytext); yylval.string = strdup(yytext);return WORKBOOK_START;}
"</ss:Workbook>"    {printf("%s",yytext); yylval.string = strdup(yytext);return WORKBOOK_END;}
"<ss:Styles>"       {printf("\t%s",yytext); yylval.string = strdup(yytext);return STYLES_START;}
```

etc..Any idea?
This is a rule that I have problem and I get an error for no detected type.
`id: ID {printf("%s",yylval.string);} EQUAL {printf("%s",yylval.string);} QUOTES {printf("%s",yylval.string);} INTEGER {printf("%s",yylval.string);} QUOTES {printf("%s",yylval.string); checkID($4);};`

Comment: In your grammar file, you should use `UPPER_CASE` only for tokens. Non-terminals should be named with `lower_case`. That makes your grammar easier to read.

Comment: To print from bison, call `printf` in the actions of the rules. Did you try that? If so, what problem did you encounter?

Comment: I tried this: for example in the first rule {printf("%s %s" ,$1,$3);} so as to print only <ss:Workbook> and </ss:Workbook> but this gave me a wrong result because it printed first the inside of the rule each time. For example,here it printed Styles first and in the end the <ss:Workbook> and </ss:Workbook>. Is there another way with yytext for example?

Comment: the bison action executes only when the entire production has been recognised. In effect, that leads to a post-order traverse of the parse tree. See "Mid-Rule Actions" in the Bison manual.

Comment: I tried to print the yytext but in some tokens (which I use them to call functions) I get the error "$3 has no declared type". However, this is very strange because I have defined the type in the %token above.

Comment: You'll need to *edit your question* with more details, then. Probably in the particular action you are talking about, `$3` does not refer to the symbol you think it does, perhaps because you miscounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule added at the end of the question is a possible way to produce output in text order rather than the post-order traverse typical of a bottom-up parser.

However, it suffers from several problems:

First, `yylval` is not meaningful in any of the mid-rule actions. Semantic values for tokens should only be referenced with `$n` references.

Second, when you are writing the `$n` references, remember that the mid-rule actions themselves count as symbols. So `$4` refers to the second mid-rule action, not the `INTEGER` token (which is `$7`).